# php fetch mysql query rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 mysql queries retrieved from my php class 2 different methods and they look as it follows

```
 SELECT
domains.id,  domains.name, domains.meta_title,
domains.meta_keywords,  domains.meta_description,
produkt_modul.keywords, produkt_modul.program_id,produkt_modul.title, produkt_modul.items, produkt_modul.search_type
 FROM domains
 JOIN produkt_modul ON domains.id = produkt_modul.domains_id WHERE domains.name='$domain_name' ORDER BY position
```

is fetching the rows for my product modules
and the second one

```
SELECT
domains.id, text_module.position, text_module.title, text_module.text
FROM    domains
JOIN    text_module
ON  domains.id = text_module.domains_id
WHERE   domains.name='$domain_name' AND active= 1 ORDER BY position
```

should give me the rows of the text modules.

When I generate the html output of the rows in my view I would like to order theme after the positions value.

what should look for example something like:

```
text_modul pos1
prod_modul pos2
prod_modul pos3
text_modul pos4
```

the actual view of the rows looks

```
text_modul1
text_modul4
prod_modul2
prod_modul3
```

How can I fetch the rows in such a way to have theme in the correct order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it in PHP. Note that this code assumes `position` is unique across both `produkt_module` and `text_module` results.

```
$allrows = array();
$res = mysql_query(/* your first query on produkt_module */);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) {
    $row['type'] = 'p';
    $allrows[$row['position']] = $row;
}

$res = mysql_query(/* your second query on text_module */);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) {
    $row['type'] = 't';
    $allrows[$row['position']] = $row;
}

ksort($allrows);  // sort all rows by position

foreach ($allrows as $pos => $row) {
    if ($row['type'] == 'p') {
        /* display a produkt_module row, i.e $row['title'], etc. */
    } elseif ($row['type'] == 't') {
        /* display a text_module row */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where the `position` column comes from but I'm guessing that the `produkt_module` and `text_module` tables both have a `position` column.

To do it in SQL you can use a UNION and sort the combined result. The restriction is that the two results UNIONed together must have the same number of columns and the columns must be compatible types:

```
SELECT title, position FROM (
  SELECT p.title, p.position
  FROM produkt_module p
  JOIN domains d ON d.id = p.domains_id
  WHERE d.name = '$domain_name'
    UNION
  SELECT t.title, t.position
  FROM text_module t
  JOIN domains d ON d.id = t.domains_id
  WHERE d.name = '$domain_name'
  AND t.active
) ORDER BY position;
```

You could also read both results sets into an array and sort that in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, I think the Union is not going to bring results in my case. Somehow I have to read the both query results in an array